# how to perform inner join on same table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have table called sla in mysql, i need to get unique switch and port_no related to perticular switch. i exactly don't know which join will help me.

```
+-------------------------+---------+
| switch                  | port_no |
+-------------------------+---------+
| 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02 | 3       |
| 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01 | 2       |
| 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01 | 1       |
| 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02 | 1       |
| 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:04 | 2       |
```

Expected output

```
+-------------------------+---------+
| switch                  | port_no |
+-------------------------+---------+
| 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:02 | 3,1     |
| 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:01 | 2,1     |
| 00:00:00:00:00:00:00:04 | 2       |
```

Comment: Google must be broken or something. Look at [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display at the application level/presentation layer (assuming you have one), e.g., a simple php loop acting upon an ordered array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got expected output by using GROUP_CONCAT function.

```
select switch,GROUP_CONCAT(port_no) from sla group by switch;
```